# Rails 4 update inside for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, controller

I have a view `show.html.eb` that displays details for an `Order` and displays all available `Delivery Slots` for the `date` of the order.

Eg:
Order 1
12/12/14
    Delivery slots:
    6.30 - 7.00
    7.30 - 8.00
    8.00 - 8.30

I then have a link next to each delivery slot which when clicked updates the field `delivery_slot` on the `Order` to the `Id` of the delivery slot that was clicked.

View Code

```
<% @slots = DeliverySlot.all.select {|slot| slot.day == @order.date} %>
<% @slots.each do |slot| %>
    <%=slot.start_time.strftime("%I:%M%p") %> - <%=slot.end_time.strftime("%I:%M%p") %>  
    <%= link_to "Order", Order.update(@order,:delivery_slot => slot) %>
    <br>
<% end %>
```

The issue is, when you click one Order link, all the order links are clicked (I can see this through the SQL in the terminal) so the end result is the `delivery_slot` field is always populated with the last delivery slot of the loop.

I appreciate that I am missing something here so could anyone explain:

1) Why all Order links are "clicked" when only 1 is clicked in practice. 
2) Is there a better way to update the `delivery_slot` attribute on the Order?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some of the generated HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally arrived at the answer:

```
<%= link_to "Order", order_path(order:{:delivery_slot_id => slot}), :method => :put %>
```

I think what tripped me up in the end was that my strong parameters specific `:delivery_slot_id` and I was specifying `:delivery_slot` so I assumed I was doing something wrong when the answer was very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are issuing an update when rendering the view.

`<%= link_to "Order", Order.update(@order,:delivery_slot => slot) %>`

You need to provide a path (or `url_options` which can be used to generate a path) as the second argument to `link_to`. Instead you are calling the `update` method. So when your view is rendered, you iterate over every delivery slot and issue an update for each one of them and as you have noted, the last one overwrites everything else.

If you observe your logs you will see that the SQL statements are seen in logs lines corresponding to the `show` request. You are updating the order even before any link is clicked.

Now since the `link_to` does not get a valid path, the actual HTML link is not pointing to anything. Clicking on it would be a no-op.

`ri link_to` is what you need to read.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this (and many other different things before) but using the Update was the only way I could get the order to update. Now I have changed the link to ` <%= link_to "Order", order_path(:delivery_slot => slot), :method => :put %> ` but I get the following error: `param is missing or the value is empty: order` with the following request `{"_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"V/CN44leUhPq21qN/osUO/X6bFywYbbU3PlaOIRw/3o=",
 "delivery_slot"=>"1619",
 "id"=>"51"}` Any ideas? The strong parameters look fine to me.